# Download ".java" files only from the given website/url

Tags: java, php, bash, shell

For some research purpose, I want to download 1000 java classes (".java") files from the given website. I don't want to do this manually.

For example, below has many Java Source files which I want to get using scripting/programming. I've worked with Linux shell scripts, PHP, and Java. So any solution using these is appreciated.

http://www.cs.uic.edu/~sloan/CLASSES/java/

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to write a program that does this? If yes, what did you try so far?

Comment: @Pierre: So far I've explored wget. Now trying to install wget package with Cygwin to try different download options with wget. If you have any other idea then please let me know. thanks

Comment: @Michael: Yes, I think wget has some options to download desired files in a recursive manner. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question

```
wget -A java -r https://www.cs.uic.edu/~sloan/CLASSES/java/
```

will download all ".java" files in the same directory structure as on the server.
This will also download the robots.txt file.

Comment: yes, it's "robots.txt" as well. But that's not an issue in my case. Thank you Roda!!

Answer (score 0):

For the particular example you gave,

```
curl -vs https://www.cs.uic.edu/~sloan/CLASSES/java/ 2>&1 | grep -oP '(?<=").*.java(?=")' | sed -e 's|^|https://www.cs.uic.edu/~sloan/CLASSES/java/|' | xargs wget
```

Explanations

1) Get the page and print to stdout. It will give you entire html.

```
curl -vs https://www.cs.uic.edu/~sloan/CLASSES/java/ 2>&1
```

2) Find the word with .java in quotes, but output without quotes `"[ANYTHING].java"`. It will give you something like `HelloWorld.java`.

```
grep -oP '(?<=").*.java(?=")'
```

3) Add prefix to make it full url, so you can download them. It will give you something like `https://www.cs.uic.edu/~sloan/CLASSES/java/HelloWorld.java`

```
sed -e 's|^|https://www.cs.uic.edu/~sloan/CLASSES/java/|'
```

4) Download them to the current directory.

```
xargs wget
```

Comment: Thank you Tin. "curl" is doing same thing, but I think "wget" does it more easily. Thank you for clean explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all !!

I've done using "wget -r -l1 -nd -nc -A.java http://www.cs.uic.edu/~sloan/CLASSES/java/"

This was however my required task. But am just thinking, may be we can improve same "wget" to go on internet and get me 1000 ".java" files. Perhaps, we can invoke google search (from script) for a keyword "java tutorials" and then from the returned URL, scan for ".java" files.

Thank again all

Viki.